# How to filter the choice list in Django Forms?

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    id          = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastname    = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    end_user_id = models.CharField(max_length=8, help_text=u"Please enter the end user id, like ABC1WZ1")
    email       = models.EmailField(max_length = 254, help_text=u'with domain ', blank=True)
    history     = HistoricalRecords()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ' ' + self.lastname

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.end_user_id = self.end_user_id.upper()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and

```
class BDO_Procedor(models.Model):
    id              = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    bdo_procedor    = models.ForeignKey(Employee,   verbose_name='bdo_procedor', on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bdo_procedor.name + ' ' + self.bdo_procedor.lastname

class BDO_ProcedorAdmin(SimpleHistoryAdmin):
    list_display            = ('id', 'bdo_procedor')
    list_filter             = ('bdo_procedor',)
    search_fields           = ['bdo_procedor']
```

At the view.py I have an assign function which assign some form to the user which also exists at the BDO_Procedor

```
def form_assign_bdo(request, pk):
    current_form = get_form(pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AssignForm(request.POST, instance=current_form)
        form.fields["assigned_to"].queryset = Employee.objects.filter(end_user_id__in=BDO_Procedor.objects.values_list('bdo_procedor__end_user_id', flat=True))
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('material_request', pk=pk)
    else:
        form = AssignForm(request.POST, instance=current_form)
    return render(request, 'app/forms/form_assign.html', {'form':form})
```

Everything working but I want to filter this list also in form, so:

```
class AssignForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AssignForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["assigned_to"].queryset = Employee.objects.filter(end_user_id__in=BDO_Procedor.objects.values_list('bdo_procedor__end_user_id', flat=True))
        

    class Meta:
        model = MissFormModel
        fields = (
            'assigned_to',  
    )
```

Everything is looking good, but when I've cliked Submit nothing is going on. What I am dooing wrong?

Comment: Could you add a check to see if `if form.is_valid():` returns True, so `else: print(form.errors.as_data()) `

Comment: What is not working when you submit? It raises an error? The form is invalid? Something else?